# How should I run a background task that also updates the UI in an intellij settings plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am adding some changes to an intelij plugin that integrates with [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) I have settings page that implements Configurable that has a form for credentials and then a "Test Login" button. On button click I want to spawn an asynchronous background task to test the credentials and then update the UI with either success or failure.

Here is a screenshot of my settings
[image]

As far as I can tell the correct way to do this would be to use a [background task](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/general-threading-rules.html#background-processes-and-processcanceledexception) but that requires a "project" which as far as I can tell you have to get from an [AnAction](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/basic-action-system.html) and I don't really see how that would work in this context. Here are a few approaches I've played around with

This still blocks the UI and spits out a warning about the UI being blocked for too long

```java
ApplicationManager.getApplication().executeOnPooledThread(() -> 
  ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLaterOnWriteThread(() -> {
                // async work
                // repaint
            }, ModalityState.stateForComponent(myMainPanel)));
```

```java
// I don't know how to get the project or if I even should here.
ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Backgroundable(project, "Login"){
    public void run(@NotNull ProgressIndicator progressIndicator) {
         // async work
         // repaint when done
    }});
```

All of this is happening in my AppSettingsComponent button click addActionListener. Here is my complete source code on [github](https://github.com/spencerdcarlson/postgres-vault-auth/tree/sdc/fix-issue-8)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the project instance required. But by looking at the Task.Backgroundable constructor you can pass a @Nullable project. So I just pass null and it works well for me.

```java
ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Backgroundable(null, "Login") {
    public void run(@NotNull ProgressIndicator progressIndicator) {
         // your stuff
    }
});
```